# Migrating from Google Apps to Office365. Prevent losing Google Cloud Services

Tags: g-suite, google-cloud-platform

My company is currently using GoogleApps and we recently set up a Google Cloud Services account to manage our DNS records.

We now are moving out of Google Apps and into Office365 and to prevent losing the management privileges on Google Cloud I tried granting permissions to my personal gmail account with no luck, it throws an error saying that the email account must be from the domain.

I have some questions regarding to this problem:

Will my GoogleApps account be deleted? 
If so, how can I prevent losing privileges in Google Cloud?

The only way out that I see is creating a generic "mycompany.admin@gmail.com" account, then create a Google Cloud Account with that Id, then migrate the DNS records to the new Google Cloud Account, finally change the DNS in the Domain Registrar.

Is there  an easier solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I will answer this if someona has the same problem.

- I was able to contact google support and they informed me that: There
  is no way of adding a non-domain (non-google-apps-account) as
  administrator for Google Cloud when Google Cloud account was created
  with a google-apps-account.
- There is also no way of migrating the Google Cloud Account.

The only solution is to create a new Google Cloud Account and manually migrating the services.